# My imagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo newer get called

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, camera

I try to write an App that needs a screen where you can take multible photos. I have used a code example from http://makeapppie.com/2015/11/04/how-to-make-xib-based-custom-uiimagepickercontroller-cameras-in-swift/.

It seems to be working OK, but my imagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo newer get called. I am getting an error message from Xcode "Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates." It sounds to me like this could be the problem, and I have googled it, but havn't gotten any wiser. A lot of people write it's an Apple bug and I havn't found anybody offering a solution.

So do anybody know if it is the Xcode error that is my problem, and in that case have a solution for that or have I written something wrong in my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, CustomOverlayDelegate {
    var picker = UIImagePickerController()

    @IBAction func shootPhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
        if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(.Rear) != nil {
            picker = UIImagePickerController() //make a clean controller
            picker.allowsEditing = false
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            picker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
            picker.showsCameraControls = false

            //customView stuff
            let customViewController = CustomOverlayViewController(
                nibName:"CustomOverlayViewController",
                bundle: nil
            )
            let customView:CustomOverlayView = customViewController.view as! CustomOverlayView
            customView.frame = self.picker.view.frame
            customView.cameraLabel.text = "Hello Cute Camera"
            customView.delegate = self

            //presentation of the camera
            picker.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
            presentViewController(picker, animated: true,completion: {
                self.picker.cameraOverlayView = customView
            })

        } else { //no camera found -- alert the user.
            let alertVC = UIAlertController(
                title: "No Camera",
                message: "Sorry, this device has no camera",
                preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(
                title: "OK",
                style:.Default,
                handler: nil)
            alertVC.addAction(okAction)
            presentViewController(
                alertVC,
                animated: true,
                completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        print("didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo")
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage //get the image from info
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(chosenImage, self,nil, nil) //save to the photo library
    }

    //What to do if the image picker cancels.
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    //MARK: Custom View Delegates
    func didCancel(overlayView:CustomOverlayView) {
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        print("dismissed!!")
    }
    func didShoot(overlayView:CustomOverlayView) {
        picker.takePicture()
        overlayView.cameraLabel.text = "Shot Photo"
        print("Shot Photo")
    }
    func weAreDone(overlayView: CustomOverlayView) {
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true,
            completion: nil)
        print("We are done!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

`picker.delegate = self` after

`picker = UIImagePickerController()`  line

Also inherit you class with UIImagePickerControllerDelegate delegate.

It will work.